# Incorrect approach for Spring Controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have two controllers. They look almost the same. First controller (WaterController) is responsible for accept data from user for consumed amount of water and save it in database. The second one (GasController) does the same only for gas. The code of these two controllers look the same, except Entities (Water and Gas).

My question is - maybe I have to somehow use the Factory method pattern to get rid of code duplication in these two controllers?
I'm not sure the Factory pattern can be applicable to the controllers. There two controllers look almost the same, but each controller operates with a specific entity (Water and Gas) to store it in a database.

The Water controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/water")
public class WaterController {

    private WaterRepository waterRepository;
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public WaterController(WaterRepository waterRepository, CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.waterRepository = waterRepository;
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getWaterById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<Water> water = waterRepository.findById(id);
        if (water.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("water record did not found by id " + id, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(water.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> createWaterConsumption(@Valid @RequestBody DataDto dataDto) {
        Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findById(dataDto.getCustomerId());
        if (customer.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("customerId " + dataDto.getCustomerId() + " did not found", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        Water water = new Water(dataDto.getConsumedAmount(), dataDto.getMonth(), customer.get());
        Water savedWater = waterRepository.save(water);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedWater.getId().toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/data")
    public List<Water> getWaterConsumptionByCustomerId(@PathVariable Long id) {
        List<Water> list = waterRepository.findAllByCustomerId(id);
        return list;
    }
}
```

The Gas controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/gas")
public class GasController {

    private GasRepository gasRepository;
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public GasController(GasRepository gasRepository, CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.gasRepository = gasRepository;
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getGasById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<Gas> gas = gasRepository.findById(id);
        if (gas.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("gas record did not found by id " + id, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(gas.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> createGasConsumption(@Valid @RequestBody DataDto dataDto) {
        Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findById(dataDto.getCustomerId());
        if (customer.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("customerId " + dataDto.getCustomerId() + " did not found", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        Gas gas = new Gas(dataDto.getConsumedAmount(), dataDto.getMonth(), customer.get());
        Gas savedGas = gasRepository.save(gas);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedGas.getId().toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/data")
    public List<Gas> getGasConsumptionByCustomerId(@PathVariable Long id) {
        List<Gas> list = gasRepository.findAllByCustomerId(id);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to club the common methods/code in a util class to respect the DRY pattern. But i believe having different controllers helps to be in-line with the separation of concern.

Comment: @AjaySinghPundir thank you for this point of view about the DRY pattern. But I'm closer to your second thought - each entity is handled by a specific controller. But on the other hand, if I need to add a new entity, I will have to add a new controller. And also I will get code duplication. And I don't know what practice is the best.

Comment: I've been in this position before.  In a simple CRUD API, most of the code is just boilerplate.  In this case, I turn to generics for the common behavior.  I've written a post on the topic, see if this is what you're looking for.  [Generic Spring API](https://www.makerofthings.io/generic-approach-for-spring-api/)

Comment: @lane.maxwell I have looked shortly on you topic. It looks like that I'm looking for! Thank you a lot! Add this information like an answer (not a comment), I will vote up your answer.

Comment: @lane.maxwell I think if you create an answer it will be more convenient for other users to find this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was recently looking at a similar issue in a project I'm working on, and I ended up creating a generic stack (controller/service/persistence).

I started with a base definition of an Entity, in my case I'm using Mongo but this will work for any persistence provider.  It takes a single generic parameter which will represent the type to be used for the id.

```
public abstract class BaseMongoDocument<ID> {
    @Id
    @Field("_id")
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private ID id;

    @CreatedBy
    @Field("created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Field("created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Field("modified_by")
    private String modifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Field("modified_date")
    private LocalDateTime modifiedDate;

    @Version
    @Field("version")
    private Long version;
}
```

Next, I'm going to create a generic service.  You'll notice the constructor takes a MongoRepository, this can easily be any of the spring data repositories.  Because Spring treats generic parameters as Qualifiers for injection, this will work nicely as you'll see in a bit.  There are intentionally two abstract methods that need to be overriden, this is to allow you to add some custom behavior (like filtering on the page and checking for optimistic locking errors on the update).  Most of the persistence logic will be implemented in this abstract class.

```
public abstract class BaseService<T extends BaseMongoDocument<ID>, ID> {
    final MongoRepository<T, ID> repository;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public BaseService(MongoRepository<T, ID> repository, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public T delete(ID id) {
        T entityToDelete = findById(id);
        repository.deleteById(id);

        return entityToDelete;
    }

    public T findById(ID id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Unable to find record with ID of " + id));
    }

    public abstract Page<T> find(Pageable pageable, String filter);

    public T create(T entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    public T update(ID id, JsonPatch jsonPatch) throws JsonPatchException, JsonProcessingException {
        T entityToPatch = findById(id);
        JsonNode patched = jsonPatch.apply(objectMapper.convertValue(entityToPatch, JsonNode.class));
        T patchedEntity = objectMapper.treeToValue(patched, (Class<T>) entityToPatch.getClass());

        return repository.save(patchedEntity);
    }

    public abstract T put(T object);
}
```

So now I have the the Service and something it can act on, let's create a generic controller.  To start out with the controller, I'm going to create a DTO interface for the transport, that will serve as a parameter to the Controller.  It's a simple interface that has but one method, and that's a method to return the entity that it's a DTO for.

```
public interface DTO<T> {
    T toEntity();
}
```

Now we're set to define the interface that will define the methods I want for my controllers (these will be the endpoints).  As parameters, it takes the type of the Entity, the DTO, and the Identifier.

```
public interface CrudControllerMethods<T, E extends DTO<T>, ID> {
    T delete(ID id);

    Page<T> find(Pageable pageable, String filter);

    List<T> findAll();

    T findById(ID id);

    T create(E dto);

    T patch(ID id, JsonPatch jsonPatch) throws JsonPatchException, JsonProcessingException;

    T put(T object);
}
```

Now, Let's create a BaseController that will implement most of these methods.

```
public abstract class BaseController<T extends BaseMongoDocument<ID>, E extends DTO<T>, ID>
        implements CrudControllerMethods<T, E, ID> {

    private final BaseService<T, ID> baseService;

    public BaseController(BaseService<T, ID> service) {
        this.baseService = service;
    }

    @Override
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public T delete(@PathVariable ID id) {
        return baseService.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public T findById(@PathVariable ID id) {
        return baseService.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @GetMapping("/page")
    public Page<T> find(Pageable pageable, @RequestParam(required = false) String filter) {
        return baseService.find(pageable, filter);
    }

    @Override
    @GetMapping
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return baseService.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @PostMapping
    public T create(@RequestBody E dto) {
        return baseService.create(dto.toEntity());
    }

    @Override
    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public T patch(@PathVariable ID id, @RequestBody JsonPatch jsonPatch) throws JsonPatchException, JsonProcessingException {
        return baseService.update(id, jsonPatch);
    }

    @Override
    @PutMapping
    public T put(@RequestBody T object) {
        return baseService.put(object);
    }
}
```

And this is what a concrete implementation of the entire stack would look like (using your Water entity).

```
@Document("Water")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(of = {"empty"})
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Water extends BaseMongoDocument<ObjectId> {
    private Boolean empty;
}
```

Next, create the DTO.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class WaterDTO implements DTO<Water> {
    private Boolean empty;

    @Override
    public Water toEntity() {
        return Water.builder().empty(empty).build();
    }
}
```

Next, define the Repository to persist the entity.

```
public interface WaterRepository extends MongoRepository<Water, ObjectId> {
}
```

Next we're going to create the service, extending our BaseService.

```
@Service
public class WaterService extends BaseService<Water, ObjectId> {
    private final WaterRepository waterRepository;

    public WaterService(WaterRepository waterRepository, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(waterRepository, objectMapper);
        this.waterRepository = waterRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Water> find(Pageable pageable, String filter) {
        return waterRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public Water put(Water water) {
        Water waterToUpdate = findById(water.getId());

        if (!water.getVersion().equals(waterToUpdate.getVersion())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The record has changed since you last retrieved it");
        }

        waterToUpdate.setEmpty(water.getEmpty());
        return waterRepository.save(waterToUpdate);
    }
}
```

The final step is to define your Controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/water")
public class WaterController extends BaseController<Water, WaterDTO, 
ObjectId> {
    public WaterController(WaterService waterService) {
        super(waterService);
    }
}
```

And, just like that, you'll have the following mappings defined:

```
GET /water/{id}
DELETE /water/{id}
GET /water/find
POST /water which takes the WaterDTO as the RequestBody
PATCH /water/{id}
```

Something to note, if you're using JPA, you'll likely need to use `@MappedSuperclass` on your base entity class.  Each time I look at this I find something additional to clean up or add to, but I think it gives you a pretty good start.

Comment: I like the idea of a `BaseController`.  I don't see that used too often.